# Why doesn't a blackhole destroy a Stargate?

Tags: stargate

In at least one episode, the SGC dials a planet that is in the midst of being destroyed by a blackhole. Will the blackhole eventually destroy the Stargate (on either end) and terminate the wormhole? If the Stargate did break, would that be enough to stop the wormhole?

Comment: Is the question, "Why wasn't that Stargate destroyed by the black hole?", or "Will it ever be destroyed by that black hole?" ?

Comment: Will it ever if there's more than one case of it encountering a blackhole

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe that because of the [time dilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation) (as depicted in the [Stargate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate) universe) that occurs near a black hole, the [Stargate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_%28device%29)'s descent into the black hole slows down relative to our time after the Stargate passes the [Event Horizon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon).

So essentially, the Stargate maybe destroyed at some point in the future, but because time relative to the Stargate will slow down exponentially, the gate will always appear to be falling towards the black hole at a relatively slower and slower rate.

[image: Time Dilation]

Furthermore, the Stargates are made of [Ancient engineered materials](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Naquadah) which makes them highly resistance to damage, and therefore Stargates may survive the [gravitational stresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress-energy-momentum_pseudotensor) of a black hole longer than a conventional object.

From [Stargate Device - Durability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_%28device%29#Durability):

> The Stargates themselves are extremely resistant to damage or
>   destruction: in one case, a Stargate survived a direct hit from a
>   meteor, while another was still capable of creating a stable
>   wormhole while on a planet near a newly formed black hole. A
>   Stargate has also been seen to continue functioning while entering a
>   star, though it was protected by a portable forcefield for a
>   portion of its journey. In the SG-1 fourth season episode "Chain
>   Reaction", the SGC sent a naquadah-enhanced nuclear bomb to a planet
>   whose surface had trace amounts of naquadah in its topsoil; the
>   explosion destroyed the entire planet, yet the gate still remained
>   open and intact.

However, the article goes on to state that a [Mark IX](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Mark_IX) is probably one of the few weapons proven to destroy a Stargate.

[image: Mark IX Gate Buster]

On another point, even if the Stargate does not slow relative to our time, it maybe on a [decaying orbit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_decay) that may take far longer than a direct path to the center of the black hole.

I'm not sure if this is how actual physics works around a black hole, but **I think this is how Stargate's writing staff looks at and depicts a black hole.**  The show [Andromeda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andromeda_%28TV_series%29) also depicted black holes in the same more-time-dilation-as-you-get-closer fashion.

**Will the black hole eventually destroy the Stargate as time approaches infinity?**

The writers never directly answer this question in the Stargate franchise, but we do see one of the [ancient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_%28Stargate%29)'s ships in [Stargate Universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_Universe) survive in close proximity to a sun's gravitational pull.  However the Stargates are not exactly depicted as invulnerable, so it is possible a black hole would eventually destroy a stargate.  It just appears to take an incredible amount of energy or force, which one might argue a black hole could possess.

Comment: this does raise an interesting question: assuming the stargate survived the tidal stresses and crossed the event horizon (from it's own proper-time perspective) would it still function as a Stargate, allowing the formation of a wormhole to tunnel in and out of the black hole?

Comment: NO. Once the event horizon is crossed that portal could no longer provide a time-responsive portal due to gravitational stresses of the event horizon. A signal might be able to go in but NOTHING (including the connection) could go out. It would be a one way trip. (Makes a great garbage can...)

Comment: @Thaddeus - Oh yeah, your right.  I should read the questions I respond to more carefully :).

Comment: In actual physics, time dilation does indeed make it so that an outside observer never actually sees something fall into a black hole. It just gets asymptotically closer to the event horizon. However, the thing falling into the black hole does see itself cross the event horizon, so I couldn't be sure what would happen with a wormhole like the stargate's. (This answer seems about as physically reasonable as you can get, though.)